# How to running shell scripts on no jailbroken iPhone

Tags: ios, bash, command

I want run shell command on iOS that is not jailbroken. I have tried searching but I haven't got an exact answer yet.

thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found this online, I hope it's helpful.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4695657?tstart=0

From this, my understanding is you can put the script into an app that you build, that can then run the script once installed on you iPhone.

It isn't the most convient way, but it will work most likely.